# Function that goes trough an array and individually apply a formula on the elements based on a "if" statement

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have an array of floats, lets say "array=([2.0, 7.0, 8.0, 1.0])", and I need to create a second array that applies a formula (out of two) to the elements of the first based on a
"if" statement applied to the respective element on a third array (let`s say, array3 = ([1, 4, 5, 1]) ). Something like "If array3_element is < 3, than array2_element = array_element * 2. If array3_element > 3, than array2_element = array_element * 3". For this example,the result for "array" would be "array2=([4.0, 21.0, 24.0, 2.0])".

The code below is my best attempt, but it doesn`t work as expected. It tests only the first element with the "if" statement and applies the same chosen formula to the role array.

```
As = np.array ([[20], [20]])

def Rsi (x, curv_adi):
    for i in def_aco(x,curv_adi):
        if abs(i) > epsilon_aco:
            return (As/10000)*(Fsd*1000)
        else:
            return (As/10000)*(Fsd*1000)*((def_aco(x,curv_adi))/(epsilon_aco))
```

*def_aco (x, curv_adi) being a function up in the code that results in "def_aco = ([2.3275, 0.1275])" and represents the "array3" on the example above. As is "array" and "array2 would be the function result.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Only the first element is tested because you `return` from the function instead of completing the for-loop.

Comment: How about using `np.where`? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's translate your code to general terms:

```
def func(array3):
     for i in array3:
        if condition:
            return array1_element
        else:
            return array3_element
```

The problem with the code is, that you will get only the first element, because you return from the function instead of iterate over all the array.

You can fix it by:

```
array2 = []
for n, i in enumerate(array3):
    if <condition>:
        array2.append(array[n])
    else:
        array2.append(array3[n])
```

If you want, you can use list comprehension instead:

```
array2 = [array[n] if <condition> else array3[n] for n, i in enumerate(array3)]
```

So, in your case you can solve it by:

```
def Rsi (x, curv_adi):
    ret = []
    for n, i in enumerate(def_aco(x,curv_adi)):
        if abs(i) > epsilon_aco:
            ret.append((As/10000)*(Fsd*1000))
        else:
            ret.append((As/10000)*(Fsd*1000)*((def_aco(x,curv_adi))/(epsilon_aco)))
    return ret
```

`

Comment: It got close! Implementing your solution got me "[array([[869.56521739],[869.56521739]]), array([[977.56717776], [ 53.56717776]])]". The answer I was hoping for is [869.56521739, 53.56717776], or the first element of the first array and the last element of the last array. Trying to tweak it and see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I substituted "As" for "As[n]" and "def_aco(x,curv_adi)" for "def_aco(x,curv_adi)[n]", both in the formulas under the "if" and "else" statements, and it kinda worked. Although the results are correct, It is still returning it as a list of arrays ( [array([869.56521739]), array([53.56717776])] ) where  the ideal would be a single array.  Still working on it.

Comment: Did it! The fix was simple. Just made "ret" a np.array. Thank you for your time! It helped a lot!!